# Replace character in a string with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have this Ansible as a String:

```
FUBAR={{ PREFIX }}_{{ CNAME }}{{ VERSION }}
```

I want to replace all `.` in the concatenated string with `''`, like this:

```
FUBAR={{ {{ PREFIX }}_{{ CNAME }}{{ VERSION }} | replace('.','') }}
```

I get the message:

```
expected token ':', got '}'
```

Could anyone give me a suggestion what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this? `FUBAR="{{ PREFIX }}_{{ CNAME }}{{ VERSION }} | replace('.', '')"`, i.e. with double quotes around the whole string?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
FUBAR="{{ ( PREFIX + '_' + CNAME + VERSION ) | replace('.','') }}"
```

Resolving a few problems:

- too many '{{}}'s
- need quotes around the whole expression
- the replace will only act on the last element unless it is all surrounded by '()'s